# rails routing: nested resources with different namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

I am trying to use the **acts_as_commentable** GEM to add comments to my Post Model. I am using ABC as namespace, so all my controller and models named as ABC::Post, ABC::User, etc.

Currently my routing setup is as following.

```
namespace :abc do
  resources :post do 
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

The routing URL generated is

```
POST   /abc/post/:id/comments(.:format)          abc/comments#create
```

How can i make it to

```
POST   /abc/post/:id/comments(.:format)         /comments#create
```

Answer (score 3):

founded the answer

```
namespace :abc do
    resources :post do 
        resources :comments, controller: '/comments'
  end
end
```