# Remove namespace from nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a namspaced resource, but I'd like a specific nested resource to route to a **non-namespaced** controller, e.g.:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts do # /admin/posts => Admin::PostsController
    resources :audits, only: [:index] # /admin/posts/1/audits => AuditsController
  end
end
```

The [guides state that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

> If you need to use a different controller namespace inside a namespace
>   block you can specify an absolute controller path, e.g: get '/foo' =>
>   '/foo#index'.

but this results in "wrong constant name" because rails tries to convert `admin//audits` in to a constant.

Comment: Why don't you take the resource you want out?

Comment: could you provide an example? I want the route nested, so I'm not sure what you recommend I do.

Comment: Well if you just let something like this `  resources :posts do # /admin/posts => Admin::PostsController
    resources :audits, only: [:index] # /admin/posts/1/audits => AuditsController
  end` it will create routes but omitting the admin namespace, is that what you want. You can have both routes

Comment: yeah, but I want the namespace for the posts resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just splitting it out completely and doing

```
get 'admin/users/:user_id/audits', to: 'audits#index'
```

Still don't really understand the quote from the guides, I assume it must be incorrect.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26926185/23723